# JS if statement - innerHTML

Tags: javascript, if-statement, innerhtml

```
function colorize(){
    for(i = 1; i<=8; i++)
    {
        var id = document.getElementById('op' + i);

        var stat = id.innerHTML;
        document.write(stat + " ");
        if(stat == 1)
        {
            id.innerHTML = "<div style='background:#00FF00; width: 20px; height: 20px; border-radius: 15px;'></div>";
        }
        else{
            id.innerHTML = "<div style='background:#FF0000; width: 20px; height: 20px; border-radius: 15px;'></div>";
        }
    }
}
```

It should check if there is a 1 or 0 and replace it with a green or red circle, but I only get red circles.

"stat" printing gave me an " 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1"  but it seem to be not working with the if statement. Does anybody know why?

Comment: stat is a string, 1 is a number. Try stat == "1"

Comment: tried that , but got the same resolt

Comment: @Thilo, yeah you're right, it's probably a space in the innerHtml...

Comment: That is also not the case though...

Comment: Can you add a document.write inside the if and else branch and post the outcome? Is there a single 1 or 0 in innerHtml?

Comment: there are no spaces there

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/ebUa7/

Comment: Why use `document.write(stat)` (losing all the type info, collapsing whitespace etc) instead of `console.log(stat)`? Except for some really edge cases, `document.write` shouldn't even be mentioned imo - especially for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `stat.length` always equals 1:

```
if(stat[0]=='1'){
```

If all you are looking for is a `1` in `stat`:

```
if(stat.match(/1/)){//contains a 1, may contain more
```

Comment: thanks! i did a print to stat.length and it returned 30 , so I found that what i was looking for is on stat[22]

Comment: @IgorGumush Oh goodness, looks like that was your problem. Also, next time, give us some info on what the `op[0-9]` div's looked like

Comment: While in this particular case it doesn't matter (that much), one shouldn't use `match` just to check whether or not a string matches a pattern: use `/pattern/.test(string)` instead. Or, if you need just to check whether or not some string contains another string, use `someStr.indexOf(anotherStr) !== -1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function colorize(){
    for(i = 1; i<=8; i++)
    {
        var id = document.getElementById('op' + i);

        var stat = id.innerHTML;
        document.write(stat + " ");
        if(stat == "1")
        {
            id.innerHTML = "<div style='background:#00FF00; width: 20px; height: 20px; border-radius: 15px;'></div>";
        }
        else{
            id.innerHTML = "<div style='background:#FF0000; width: 20px; height: 20px; border-radius: 15px;'></div>";
        }
    }
}
```