# Change innerHTML based on ID using Javascript didn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

How do I change the text (innerHTML) of an element by its ID. I'm pretty sure my code is right, read some examples online but somehow it didn't work.
Code as shown in image...

[image: Code example]

Another thing, I want to create if statement for it to change OFF to ON and vice versa.
if text = State: ON, text = State: OFF else text = State: ON.
[image]

Comment: Try `onclick="changefantext()"`

Comment: And in the second picture your assignment is using `==` instead of `=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be

```
onclick="changefantext()"
```

To see whether it is ON or OFF you could use [String.substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) to extract the last two or three characters of the text. You can read the text using innerHTML again.

Alternatively, you can attach a property to the element:

```
if (document.getElementById('fan').isOn == 'undefined') {
    document.getElementById('fan').isOn == true;
} else if (document.getElementById('fan').isOn == true) {
    // etc.
```

You should preferably create an object variable that refers to this element:

```
var myFan = document.getElementById('fan');
```

**Added**: The innerHTML will include whitespace, so it won't match "State: OFF" - that is, it isn't an exact match. Use `indexOf` to discover if it contains the word "OFF". This returns a number of 0 or more if the text is found:

```
var fan = document.getElementById('fan');
var fanText = fan.innerHTML;

if (fanText.indexOf("OFF") >= 0) {
    // it is OFF
```

Comment: Ah, it worked. Lol, I guess I'm too tried and didn't see that. Now, the IF statement. I'll try to get it to work, if I can't I'll ask again. Edit: I am looking at this thread right here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16881302/js-if-statement-innerhtml

Comment: I added another photo with my way, can you check what's wrong with it? Thank you for your code but I don't quite understand. That's why I try with my code approach, do tell me what's wrong. Edit: I haven't put the code for ElseIF because the default state if OFF so, I want to try to turn it ON first.